# Bluetooth track control not working anymore

Tags: bluetooth, android-11, spotify

All of a sudden I noticed that my Bluetooth headphones (one Bose, one Sony) **cannot control tracks on Spotify anymore**, i.e. play/pause, skip, previous, etc. do all not work anymore. Volume control is the only thing that still works.
The devices are flawless, they can still control tracks on my Laptop.

I also tried YT music, there the controls do not work either, so I assume it's not a Spotify issue.

Android 11 on Fairphone 3, Build number 8901.4.A.0016.6.

What else did it try?

- Restarted the phone
- Unpaired devices and paired again
- Reset the Wi-Fi, mobile & Bluetooth connection (System > Reset options)